# SharePoint 2013 - redirect user back to my home page instead of OOTB SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, I have created several custom pages and have modified each of their "advanced" share with settings, so that each of these pages has unique permissions based on what role you are.  I have successfully logged in with specific user account that has a specific role type, and tested what SharePoint will do when this user tries to access a page they do not have permissions for.  SharePoint redirects this user to a page that says the following message...

"Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."

But is there any way I can set the redirect to a page my choosing? Such as back to my home page?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: good question! I would say use CEWP but I'm not sure that would even get hit. Maybe a custom HTTP Handler in VS would work

Comment: man it would be so nice if there were redirect options for this under page share settings, ahhhhh!

Comment: right! Seems like it should be OOB, I'm going to read up because this would be useful. But at the same time users may get confused without a warning letting them know. Maybe not for your situation

Comment: Oh, what you could did is modify AccessDenied.aspx and put a link on the bottom like 'Return to Home page'. Even read the Query string to only display it if it matches a specific page

Comment: what would be a good way to access and brand that page without breaking any OOTB components associated to that page? I simply want to overlay the look and feel, and also apply links for the user to go back home if they do encounter that page.

Comment: I'll have to play with it. I will post an answer once I find a good solution

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe I'm doing this, it is by no means support and could be overwritten anytime if you push an update, but here is a solution I developed for you. Open AccessDenied.aspx in the _layouts folder.

In 'PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea', place a div with a message indicating the user will be redirected to the homepage

```
   <div style='display:block'>You will be redirected to the homepage in 3 seconds...</div>
```

In 'PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead' add the script block to redirect them:

```
<script>
  window.setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = "http://www.yourSPsite.ca";
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

It is possible to detect the page by the 'Source' QueryString and perform the redirect accordingly.

This is a quick HACK! If you want to do it right, do some research on modifying resx files, or developing a custom error page:

http://blog.randomdust.com/index.php/2013/07/custom-access-denied-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5c40d604-bdb4-405a-88d6-a0d3b4eb0af1/how-to-set-custom-access-denied-pages-in-sharepoint-2013

[image]

Comment: It may be even better to add the script in the error15.master

Comment: Thank you bro!  Let me play with this next week and get back with you.  thanks again! +1 on the work!

Comment: NP man, good luck, update when you can